# Could anyone help me with the meaning of this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the sentence:

> I don’t go to Australia because I dream about the outback only to turn around and say, “No, that trip is a bit out of my budget. Maybe another time.”

My questions are :1) Why the author don't go to Australia; 2) for the part after "only to turn around...", how does it connect to the previous part?

Can any friend help me with this?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We use 'only to' to introduce something which is unexpected or disappointing when one considers what was said or written before.

*I ran all the way to the shop, **only to** find that it was closed.*

*I read the book with great interest, **only to** find that the last page was missing.*

2. We use the expression 'turn around and say (or do) *something*' to describe a situation where someone says or does something that we did not expect or hope for.

*Mary kept saying she loved me, then **turned around and** told me she didn't want to see me any more.*

*My cousin promised me that I could buy his car, then **turned around and** sold it to someone else.*

Note: this is a figure of speech; no physical turning around is required.

In your example sentence the speaker is saying they dream about the outback (in Australia) and then decide not to go there because a trip to Australia would cost more money than they have to spend on a vacation at that time.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. I puzzled over the way how author expressed the causal relationship. But after you bringing the meaning out, I understood the sentence. After seeing your post, I also spoke out this sentence a few times and the structure of this sentence and how it used made more sense to me. I see where it coming from. Thank you very much.